# Uitabviewcontroller How to open the 2nd viewcontroller in uitabbarcontroller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I have one button when i click that button i want open tabviewcontroller 2nd index. here my question how to push the another viewcontroller

```
 -(IBAction)Chat:(id)sender;
{
[self.parentViewController.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:2];
}
```

Comment: Do you want to open 2nd view controller in Tabviewcontroller, or push to the another viewcontroller by navigationcontroller?

Comment: i want to open 2nd viewcontroller when i clickt that button

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
[self.parentViewController.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:2];
```

You need to use this:

```
[self.TabBarController setSelectedIndex:2];
```

I hope It will work for you.